# How to add push notification for a particular folder in google drive to get all updates that happen for all the file inside the folder

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api

I want to set a push notification for a folder in google drive using google api such that any changed made to any file inside that folder than i get a call -back.

Comment: That would indeed be a cool feature, but isn't currently possible

Comment: This would the one you are requesting for: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/fsYwbZ3hpjc%5B1-25%5D . If yes add your comment there. Hope that helps!

Comment: @KRR I mean to use it for api usage. not for email.

Comment: @Divyesh https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push

Answer (score 2):

What I know is that its not possible at this moment. Instead of that you can create `changes` hook and get informed if ANY file on drive is changed. After theat run file search request to find all files within given folder by passing its ID, ie:

```
"'<folder_id>' in parents"
```

where `<folder_id>` is id of the folder where you want to look for changes. You can then look for last modified date and compare to your own cache, for example stored on your server in cache files. If file is newer than do with it whatever you want (and of course update cache).

please refer to:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/watch
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters